# What is the result of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)(\frac{5}{6})^{n-1}$?

Tags: summation

In wolfram alpha it says it's 30 but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Do you know Taylor series?

Comment: Oh well its already answered, I think its duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1) (5/6)^{n-1}= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} m (5/6)^m$$
Take infinite G.P
$$(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k,~~ |x|<1$$
D.w.r.t.$x$ and multiply by $x$ on both sides to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k x^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
Using this we get
$$S=\frac{5/6}{(1-5/6)^2}=30.$$

Comment: You forgot to square the denominator in the last line.

Comment: Thanks I edited it up.